# Which layout manager do I need to use?

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I need to design the frame shown in the image using Swing. I am fed up in aligning the components as shown in the figure. Can anybody please give me a clue on what layout manager I need to use to align components like this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use a GridBagLayout. It is a more versatile GridLayout. It allows you to customize grid width, grid height, and more. [GridBagLayout examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Can anybody please give me a clue on what layout manager

Well you could use a `GridBagLayout` if you want to use a single panel with a single layout manager. The coding becomes more complex because you need to specify the grid location of each component.

Or, you could use multiple panels each with a different layout manager. Start with a panel that uses a vertical `BoxLayout`. Then you can add the label to the panel. Then create a second panel with a `GridLayout`. Add the radio buttons to this panel and then add the panel to the panel using the BoxLayout. Finally you add the BoxLayout panel to the "PAGE_START" of the frame.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for more information and working examples. The key point is you are never forced to use a single layout manager. This allows you to design the form more logically.

Answer (score 0):

You need [GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html).
Check the sample you can find there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably just use a standard border layout if you are going for the easy solution.

Panel North, Panel Center, Panel South.

Add your JLabel to the north panel. 
Add your buttons to the other two panels.

Then create a main panel and add north, center, south.

As others have suggested using grid would be the most professional but if you want easy then border layout will work.